# Copy row data into another row with URL?

Tags: excel, csv, url

I tried doing some research in finding a way to move a row of SKUs into another row with the start of a URL and end with .jpg. It seems to be a simple code but couldn't figure out how to change the code to adding the before and after of the URL. I'm not to good with excel so I'm not sure if I need a function or a VBA code. To start I'm just trying to learn so when I get the file I"m familiar.

So, I have 10,000+ SKUs in row "C" I want the outcome in row "F" to be [www.example.com/123456789.jpg](http://www.example.com/123456789.jpg)

C > F ([www.example.com/"sku".jpg](http://www.example.com/%22sku%22.jpg))

CSV file can work correctly without having to do it manually.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The links do not work for me. Can you write your example as text in the question? Otherwise there is not enough information.

Comment: I think what you need is a way to extract the SKU out from a URI, right? If so, please edit your post and ask thereal question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to put the SKUs on front of an URI... So using formulas, you can do it like this:

```
="www.exampleurl.com/"&C2&".jpg"
```

Where C2 is the cell where the SKU is. It'd thou copy that formula, it will increase the`C2` into `C1000` if that's what you need

Comment: I found out this code would work:
=CONCATENATE("https://example.com/",A1,".jpg")

Comment: Yes, that works, but has limits and sometimes thorows errors, while using `&` is taken as string concatenation without limit